# Nullpointer when switching back to HomeFragment

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, fragment, android-arrayadapter

I have this error which keeps bugging me. I am using a NavDrawer where I have two items, Home and Admin.

Every time I switch from Home to Admin and switch back to Home again I get a nullpointer exception. I don't know how to solve it but I think it may involve something with onAttach()?

I appreciate any kind of help.

```
package com.example.slidingmenu;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import services.JSONRequest;

import model.Post;

import adapter.PostAdapter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private ListView mainListView;
    private MyRequestReceiver receiver;

    public HomeFragment() {}

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedIntanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        mainListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MyRequestReceiver.PROCESS_RESPONSE);
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        receiver = new MyRequestReceiver();
        getActivity().getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        new RequestItemsServiceTask().execute();
        return rootView;
    }

    private class RequestItemsServiceTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog = 
                new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {         
                try {
                    getPostInfo();
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            if(dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }       
    }

    private void getPostInfo() {
        boolean internet = isNetworkAvailable(this.getActivity());
        if(internet) {
            Intent msgIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), JSONRequest.class);
            msgIntent.putExtra(JSONRequest.IN_MSG, "getPostInfo");
            getActivity().startService(msgIntent);
        } else {
            Log.d("WHAT?", "What just happened?");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void displayPostInfo(String response) {
        JSONObject responseObj = null;

        try {
            responseObj = new JSONObject(response);

            boolean success = responseObj.getBoolean("success");
            if(success) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                JSONArray postInfo = responseObj.getJSONArray("postInfo");
                JSONObject JSONObj = postInfo.toJSONObject(postInfo);

                ArrayList<Post> postList = new ArrayList<Post>();

                for (int i = 0; i < JSONObj.length() ; i++) {
                    String str = postInfo.getString(i) + "";
                    Post post = gson.fromJson(str, Post.class);
                    postList.add(new Post(post.getPostId(), post.getPostTitle(), post.getPostContent()));
                }

                PostAdapter adapter = new PostAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item_row, postList);

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View header = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
                mainListView.addHeaderView(header);
                mainListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {

            }

        } catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = 
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if(connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if(info != null) {
                for(int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                    Log.w("INTERNET:", String.valueOf(i));
                    if(info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        Log.w("INTERNET:", "connected!");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public class MyRequestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public static final String PROCESS_RESPONSE = "com.services.intent.action.PROCESS_RESPONSE";
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String response = null;
            String responseType = intent.getStringExtra(JSONRequest.IN_MSG);

            if(responseType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("getPostInfo")) {
                response = intent.getStringExtra(JSONRequest.OUT_MSG);
                Log.d("Response", response);
                displayPostInfo(response);
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Here is the error log:

```
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.services.intent.action.PROCESS_RESPONSE cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.example.slidingmenu.HomeFragment$MyRequestReceiver@4172f958
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:773)
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at adapter.PostAdapter.<init>(PostAdapter.java:22)
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.example.slidingmenu.HomeFragment.displayPostInfo(HomeFragment.java:119)
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.example.slidingmenu.HomeFragment.access$1(HomeFragment.java:99)
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.example.slidingmenu.HomeFragment$MyRequestReceiver.onReceive(HomeFragment.java:163)
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:763)
03-12 13:46:47.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     ... 9 more
```

Comment: What is on line 119 of `HomeFragment.java`?

Comment: PostAdapter adapter = new PostAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item_row, postList);

Comment: Sorry I meant to say line 163 of `HomeFragment.java`

Comment: displayPostInfo(response); --- this method

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
 if(responseType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("getPostInfo"))
```

is probably always false, hence living `response` with a `null` initialization.

Comment: I think you are right. I don't get the error now at least. Thanks dude.

Comment: Or maybe I was a bit too quick to vote your answer. Now I don't see any items in the listview. :S

Comment: I don't think it's this line which causes it.

Comment: Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: @Ilhami you can post a new question.